# How to print multiple txt files from a single output

Tags: python

I want to write different text files from each group; how do I go about it? Currently it's writing everything into one txt file.

```
data = json.loads(output)
print "===========================Example 1======================================="
for issue in data["issues"]:
    print issue ['key'], issue['fields']['summary']

data = json.loads(output1)
print"======================Example 2===================================="
for issue in data["issues"]:
   print issue ['key'], issue['fields']['summary']

data = json.loads(output2)
print"====================== Example 3===================================="
for issue in data["issues"]:
    print issue ['key'], issue['fields']['summary']

data = json.loads(output3)
print"======================Example 4===================================="
for issue in data["issues"]:
    print issue ['key'], issue['fields']['summary']    

data = json.loads(output4)
print"======================Example 5===================================="
for issue in data["issues"]:
    print issue ['key'], issue['fields']['summary']
```

Thia is how I have solved this issue :

```
for issue in data["issues"]:
   f.write(issue ['key'])
   f.write(issue['fields']['summary']) 
   f.write('\n')
```

It writes every thing in a list and in separate files under each line.

Comment: Hint: strings, concatenation, write-string-to-file

Comment: If my response below answers your question appropriately, please mark this question as answered. Otherwise, elaborate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just printing, not writing to file in your example.
Also, what would you do if there were 100 outputs?

Pseudocode example of simplified solution:

```
output1 = {...}
outputs = (output1, output2, output3)

for index, output in enumerate(outputs):
    filename = 'output_data_{0}'.format(index)

    #this will write file in directory relative to script location
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('Example {0}:\r\n'.format(index))

        for issue in data["issues"]:
            # assumes issue is of type dict
            # assumes issues has appropriate keys
            # assumes values are of string type
            key = issue['key']
            summary = issue['fields']['summary']

            f.writelines((key, summary, "\r\n",))
```

For Python file object documentation:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=open#file
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

Also, note that this solution is not type safe, and care should be taken to ensure a string is passed to the file object's write method.

Comment: Nice, +1. Some hints: `write` takes only one argument (no `,` like in `print`); add a "\n" after writing the issues; you could include the `json` call into the loop (`data` is never created); and better use `with open(...) as f`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I know my code was repetitive I will work on making it shorter.

Comment: Nice catch Tobias. `writelines` method would be the correct method to implement in this case. I'll update my example to reflect that, the new line characters, and `with` statement. Thanks.

Comment: missing `)` after `f.write`, and `writelines` takes one argument, which is a sequence. Here you are passing it three arugments - and it will result in an error.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I fixed the example so that `writelines` is now passed a tuple. Please note that the example was intended to be pseudocode.